# Powershell script to create some users and renaming some users is working when executing it within the powershell but not from the batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, exe

I have a PowerShell script which is used to create some users and to rename some users and its working fine when we execute it within the PowerShell (when PowerShell is running as administrator).

I have some requirements and I have to create simple executable file of this PowerShell script so every user could execute it just by double clicking on it.

For this purpose, I have created a .bat file which will execute the PowerShell script with admin rights but it's not working by double clicking the .bat file.

The .bat file is as under:

```bash
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""C:\Users\aalih\Desktop\Final\first.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
pause
```

On running the .bat file, I could see the following error in the Event Viewer:

```
Session "PerfDiag Logger" failed to start with the following error: 0xC0000035
```

Any help to make this .bat file to run the script would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the ".exe" the requirement, the "every user could execute it just by double clicking on it", or both?  There is a technique for embedding PowerShell scripts in a CMD files (Batch file).  And, with a little experimenting, an alternative would be to bypass the batch file and execute the ps1, or exe, from a shortcut (with RunAs defined in the shortcut) from the user's desktop (or other location).  But, in either case, if admin permissions is needed, then user has to have those rights.

Comment: Basically, the requirement is anything that "every user" can double click to run so a batch file is OK. But I created the batch file (shown in the post) and after double clicking it, Windows asks if I want to run PowerShell as administrator, when I click "Yes", it just exits doing nothing.

Comment: If you already have an exe version of the ps1 file, what happens if you 1) Create a shortcut to that exe (In Windows Explorer hold Ctrl+Shift while dragging the exe file), 2) Edit the properties of the shortcut as described [here](https://www.top-password.com/blog/make-your-program-always-run-as-administrator/) 3) Execute the shortcut as the user?  Also, UAC can kill things like this without throwing any errors or warnings.  So you may want to disable UAC during some of the test just to see if that is causing the problems.

Comment: By "Edit the properties of the shortcut" I'm thinking of setting the Run-As properties.